# How do I make a command give the first mention a role with the ID "973182673306660885"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have tried the below but i get the error: "msg.mentions.users.first.addRole is not a function"

```
let BotBanRole = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "973182673306660885");
  const FMT = msg.mentions.users.first();

if (msg.content.startsWith('$BotBan')) {
    if (FMT === undefined) {
      msg.reply('Did not detect user')
    return; // Do not proceed, there is no user.
  }
  const FM = FMT.username;
  // Do stuff with the username
    msg.mentions.users.first.addRole(BotBanRole);
    msg.reply('Bot Banned ' + FM.tag)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close, give this a try.

```js
const BotBanRole = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "973182673306660885");
const FMT = msg.mentions.members.first();

if (msg.content.startsWith('$BotBan')) {
    if (!FMT) {
        msg.reply('Did not detect user')
        return;
    } else {
        FMT.roles.add(BotBanRole);
        msg.reply(`Bot Banned ${FMT.user.username}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not totally right. You can't fetch roles of a user. You picked it by `mentions.users` but tried to add it role. That's wrong. You can only add role if it's a member. So you should give a chance to try `msg.mentions.members.first()` ^^

Comment: Good catch, I just copied and edited existing code didn't even see that it said users and not members, I have updated the answer

Comment: Yeah, actually there's more error if you look at properly. You can't get username of a member... Also there's simplier way to get role with ID like; `msg.guild.roles.cache.get("id")`..

Comment: Added `.user` and yes I'll agree that it is simpler to do it that way

Comment: You did a great job with this it is easy to understand and compact

Answer (score 0):

```js
let BotBanRole = msg.guild.roles.cache.get("973182673306660885");
const FMT = msg.mentions.members.first();

if (msg.content.startsWith('$BotBan')) {
    if (!msg.mentions.members.first()) {
      msg.reply('Did not detect user')
    return; // Do not proceed, there is no user.
  }
  const FM = FMT.user;
  // Do stuff with the username
    FMT.roles.add(BotBanRole);
    msg.reply('Bot Banned ' + FM.tag)
}
```

I edited your code and if it's v13, it works like this.